# Why don't we use an intrinsic semi conductor as a collector in an npn BJT device?

Tags: semiconductor-physics, electronics

I was watching a video lecture which talked about how the doping level is varied across the Collector and the various reasons behind doing this.

There was also the question about why Intrinsic semiconductor isn't used  for the collector region? Like, because of no doping, the free charge carriers will be less. So, the depletion region between the base and collector won't increase ( i.e, decreasing the influence of early effect and making the collector current almost a constant) when the Collector emitter region is reverse biased.
***Now, according to the video lecture, an intrinsic conductor due to it's low conductivity will hinder the flow of electrons from the emitter side, thus again affecting the collector current.***

I don't understand this explanation. An intrinsic semi conductor lacks sufficient free charge carriers and hence has a low conductivity.
However, in the case of an NPN BJT, there are electrons entering from the emitter to the collector, right? So, won't these electrons act like charge carriers and conduct the current ? Hence , we can use an intrinsic semiconductor as a collector.

Please help me identify the mistake in my thinking. Where am I going wrong in this ?

Comment: Well, you can inject carriers but they will recombine in the intrinsic region to keep $np=n_{i}^{2}$ locally.

Comment: Assume the  intrinsic region has 'p' amount of holes and 'n' amount of electrons. Now, an 'x' amount of electrons enter this region. Some electrons from this 'x' will recombine with the 'p' , right? But even then, given the low value of 'p' the recombination won't be huge i guess.